# Focus on next input while keeping the keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I am creating a web-app **without** using React, where a user needs to fill in four digits. After every entry (keyUp), I use a piece of JQuery that focuses on the next digit:

```
      $this.next(".inputs").focus();
```

This results however in a flickering keyboard on mobile devices; *the keyboard quickly disappears and reappears again*.

Is there a way to keep the keyboard "up" when focusing on the next input field.

Any help would be much appreciated, I found some solutions online but they are all for applications where React is used.